# write file, st_mtime doesn't change

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

I have a program that wants to check if a file has been modified.  The regtest fails, and, indeed, despite the file having changed, the `st_mtime` has not!  Moreover, an external stat confirms the same.

I believe st_mtime *should* change because stat(2) says

> The field st_mtime is changed  by  file  modifications,  for  example,  by  mknod(2),  truncate(2), utime(2)  and  write(2) (of more than zero bytes).

Here's a bit of C code that illustrates the matter:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void touch(const char *fn, const char *contents)
{
    FILE *fp;
    assert(fp = fopen(fn, "w"));
    fprintf(fp, contents);
    fclose(fp);
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    struct stat st;
    char path[] = "/tmp/foo";
    time_t m1, m2;
    unsigned int t;

    touch(path, "hello\n");
    assert(!stat(path, &st));
    m1 = st.st_mtime;

    touch(path, "hello, world!\n");
    t = sleep(2);
    assert(!stat(path, &st));
    m2 = st.st_mtime;

    printf("Sleep remaining: %lu\n", t);
    printf("Elapsed modtime=%lu\n", m2 - m1);
}
```

Here's something to offer to bash to confirm that it's not just caching within the C program:

> $ while true; do stat /tmp/foo | grep Modify; sleep 1;done

Any suggestions what is happening?  Fwiw, this is running on a system thus identified:

```
jeff@london:src $ uname -a
Linux london 2.6.32-37-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 20:32:42 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jeff@london:src $
```

Comment: how do you change the file you check? It might be worth considering an error in that step before analyzing you code.

Comment: The function touch() makes the change.  It's just the C equivalent of "echo $1 > /tmp/foo".

Comment: Looking at the file from the shell, I confirm that it has the contents from the second change but the modtime from the first!

Comment: some mounting options may affect the way the mtime is updated inside inodes.

Comment: @Basile - true, but in this case the code is at fault.  However those mounting options do update metadata at file close time.  McKusick's BSD ffs was aware of this issue back in the 1980's, i.e., updating metadata (like mtime) with every physical write incurs extra overhead, because it means one extra I/o to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I'd strongly encourage you to not use statements with side effects within `assert`s.  I understand it's convenient and if the code is never going to go production it doesn't really matter, but it's not good form.  In particular, if you ever define `NDEBUG`, the `assert`s get converted to a noop, the code for the condition is never executed.

Now then, the problem is most likely that you put the `sleep` call after both `touch` calls, instead of between them.  Change this:

```
touch(path, "hello\n");
assert(!stat(path, &st));
m1 = st.st_mtime;

touch(path, "hello, world!\n");
t = sleep(2);
assert(!stat(path, &st));
m2 = st.st_mtime;
```

to

```
touch(path, "hello\n");
int rv = stat(path, &st);
assert(!rv);
m1 = st.st_mtime;

t = sleep(2);

touch(path, "hello, world!\n");
int rv = stat(path, &st);
assert(!rv);
m2 = st.st_mtime;
```

Comment: Um, yes, I'm a moron.  Thanks for pointing me at the obvious...  This was a contrived example from some rather more complicated code, and I clearly proofread what I thought I'd written.

Comment: And the much more complicated bit of real-life code had the same bug.  I am more consistent than I dare dream.

Answer (score 1):

**Never use `assert`** on functions with side effects!

Always do this:

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(...);

assert(fp != NULL);
```

The entire line containing the `assert()` disappears from release builds.

Comment: Agreed, and thanks.  It was meant in this throw-away example to rule out bad return values in the example.